# How to define yaml sequence mapping serialization styles?

Tags: serialization, yaml

There are 2 variants of list to mapping in yaml:

```
-
  name: Mark McGwire
  hr:   65
  avg:  0.278
```

and

```
- name: Mark McGwire
  hr:   65
  avg:  0.278
```

How do define this difference for serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML spec calls the second form *compact notation*. There is no semantic difference. An implementation is not required to let you choose between the two representations.

The only implementation I know of that lets you choose between these representations is ruamel via `yaml.compact()`, [see here](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html?highlight=compact).